# How do I collect the in_app_purchase event(iOS)?

Tags: ios, firebase, in-app-purchase, in-app-events

I know that the in_app_purchase event is automatically collected as it is a basic event.
Android apps are being automatically collected.
However, the iOS app is not being collected.
I've been looking through the manual, but I can't seem to find it.
Anyone who knows, please help.

I've looked all the ways, but I can't find a way.

Comment: You would need to write your own code to post an event in your transaction queue processing object

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you for giving me hope. Is it true that it is not originally collected automatically? Do we need to do something extra? I would be very grateful if you could explain a little more in detail.